# I can't make commands in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I'm having a problem with discord.py.
I'd like to make a command to kick/ban people.
I tried this at first and it didn't work, so I went to check if commands worked at all for me. Apparently it doesn't. I've tried everything and nothing works.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
Token = 'TOKEN'


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('test')


client.run(Token)
```

I type !test on the channel but nothing happens.
I've tried basically everything.
I've changed the prefix, done: `@bot.command(name='test)`, basically everything you could think of. Nothing works. I'd like to know if I'm missing something crucial. Like do I have to download something first or am I missing something in the code or are there permissions I need to enable. I've looked all over the discord py API reference. Anything would be helpful thanks.

Comment: Does the bot become active when you run the code?

Comment: Well since there is a delay between when you don't run the bot anymore until it shows as offline, i dont know if it becomes active but ill turn it off until it goes offline and then try that

Comment: Can you try to change `client.run(Token)` to `bot.run(Token)`

Comment: @Nurqm yes the bot comes active i tested that with the on_ready event reference

Comment: @Nurqmno i cant change it to `bot.run(Token)` I get this: `discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.`

Comment: Is there any error showing up or just the command is not working?

Comment: Is it possible that it won't work because of the wrong version or my os or smthn, i use linux(beta) by the way so maybe thats why it doesnt work

Comment: no error the command just doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221019/discussion-between-nurqm-and-remi-zacharias).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because of `bot = commands.Bot()`. You can use this code instead:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
await ctx.send('test')
client.run(token)
```

So you just have to delete `bot = commands.Bot()` then replace the `@bot.command()` with `@client.command`.